# My app crashes every time I click a button to activate a second activity

Tags: android, android-activity

I am currently trying to make a lockscreen app. It has two activities. The **first activity** consists in a simple layout with a button. The button is supposed to activate the **second activity** and set the lockscreen but everytime I click the button, my app crashes. Any help and explanation would be appreciated. Thank you.

---

**First Activity**

```
package com.hariton.firstnew;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;

public class HelloWorld extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_hello_world);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Lockscreen has been set.", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
    }

    //set_button
    public void setLockScreen(View view) {
        Intent lockActivity = new Intent(this, SetLockScreenActivity.class);
        startActivity(lockActivity);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_hello_world, menu);
        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

**Second Activity**

```
package com.hariton.firstnew;

import android.app.KeyguardManager;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.telephony.PhoneStateListener;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;

import com.hariton.firstnew.utils.LockscreenService;
import com.hariton.firstnew.utils.LockscreenUtils;

public class SetLockScreenActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
        LockscreenUtils.OnLockStatusChangedListener {

    // User-interface
    private Button btnUnlock;

    // Member variables
    private LockscreenUtils mLockscreenUtils;

    // Set appropriate flags to make the screen appear over the keyguard
    @Override
    public void onAttachedToWindow() {
        this.getWindow().setType(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_KEYGUARD_DIALOG);
        this.getWindow().addFlags(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                        | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED
                        | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON
                        | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD
        );

        super.onAttachedToWindow();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.content_set_lock_screen);

        init();

        // unlock screen in case of app get killed by system
        if (getIntent() != null && getIntent().hasExtra("kill")
                && getIntent().getExtras().getInt("kill") == 1) {
            enableKeyguard();
            unlockHomeButton();
        } else {

            try {
                // disable keyguard
                disableKeyguard();

                // lock home button
                lockHomeButton();

                // start service for observing intents
                startService(new Intent(this, LockscreenService.class));

                // listen the events get fired during the call
                StateListener phoneStateListener = new StateListener();
                TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
                telephonyManager.listen(phoneStateListener,
                        PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);

            } catch (Exception e) {
            }

        }
    }

    private void init() {
        mLockscreenUtils = new LockscreenUtils();
        btnUnlock = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnUnlock);
        btnUnlock.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // unlock home button and then screen on button press
                unlockHomeButton();
            }
        });
    }

    // Handle events of calls and unlock screen if necessary
    private class StateListener extends PhoneStateListener {
        @Override
        public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {

            super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);
            switch (state) {
                case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
                    unlockHomeButton();
                    break;
                case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
                    break;
                case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
                    break;
            }
        }
    };

    // Don't finish Activity on Back press
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

        return;
    }

    // Handle button clicks
    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME)
        {
            Log.i("Home Button", "Clicked");
        }
        if(keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)
        {
            finish();
        }
        return false;
    }

    // handle the key press events here itself
    public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
        if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP
                || (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN)
                || (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_POWER)) {
            return false;
        }
        if ((event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME)) {

            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    // Lock home button
    public void lockHomeButton() {
        mLockscreenUtils.lock(SetLockScreenActivity.this);
    }

    // Unlock home button and wait for its callback
    public void unlockHomeButton() {
        mLockscreenUtils.unlock();
    }

    // Simply unlock device when home button is successfully unlocked
    @Override
    public void onLockStatusChanged(boolean isLocked) {
        if (!isLocked) {
            unlockDevice();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        unlockHomeButton();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    private void disableKeyguard() {
        KeyguardManager mKM = (KeyguardManager) getSystemService(KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
        KeyguardManager.KeyguardLock mKL = mKM.newKeyguardLock("IN");
        mKL.disableKeyguard();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    private void enableKeyguard() {
        KeyguardManager mKM = (KeyguardManager) getSystemService(KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
        KeyguardManager.KeyguardLock mKL = mKM.newKeyguardLock("IN");
        mKL.reenableKeyguard();
    }

    //Simply unlock device by finishing the activity
    private void unlockDevice() {

        finish();
    }
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.hariton.firstnew">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".HelloWorld"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".SetLockScreenActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_set_lock_screen"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"></activity>

        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**This is the logcat error I get:**

> ```
> FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.hariton.firstnew, PID: 12523
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Window type can not be changed after the window is added.
>
>   at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1624)
>   at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1573)
>   at android.view.IWindowSession$Stub$Proxy.relayout(IWindowSession.java:956)
>   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.relayoutWindow(ViewRootImpl.java:6684)
>   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1994)
>   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1437)
>   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7397)
>   at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:920)
>   at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:695)
>   at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:631)
>   at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:906)
>   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7229)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
> ```

Comment: try writing this in your oncreate method this.getWindow().setType(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_KEYGUARD_DIALOG);
        this.getWindow().addFlags(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                        | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED
                        | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON
                        | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD

Comment: Unfortunately it dosen't work but thanks for the fast response.

Comment: what is the minimum sdk of your app ??